# using cloud firestore and cloud functions within unity app safely

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In my Unity project, I'm using simple web requests (POST requests) to store and retrieve information from the Cloud Firestore, and it is all working fine.

The POST requests are made to some Cloud Functions that do all the job in the database.

The thing is I'm using the database with all permission (read and write) granted to everyone.

I don't know how to safely allow this operations. What I mean by this is if I'm an user of the app (and I'm INSIDE the app), then I should be able to read and write from the database, but outside the app nobody should be allowed to do any modification in the database.

How can I secure my database within these constraints? I read about Firebase auth but I didn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to learn about Firestore security rules.  It's a long and complex topic, and impossible to say for sure exactly what's required for your case.  But you can start [reading the documentation about it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview).